# Debugging a print DataFrame issue in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I debug a problem with printing a Pandas DataFrame ? I call this function and then print the output (which is a Pandas DataFrame).

```
n=ion_tab(y_ion,cycles,t,pH)
print(n)
```

The last part of the output looks like this:

```
58       O2  1.784306e-35       4      86  7.3
60    HCO3-  5.751170e+02       5      86  7.3
61     Ca+2  1.825748e+02       5      86  7.3
62      CO2  3.928413e+01       5      86  7.3
63  CaHCO3+  3.755015e+01       5      86  7.3
64    CaCO3  4.616840e+00       5      86  7.3
65    SO4-2  1.393365e+00       5      86  7.3
66    CO3-2  8.243118e-01       5      86  7.3
67    CaSO4  7.363058e-01       5      86  7.3
        ...           ...     ...     ...  ...

[65 rows x 5 columns]
```

But if I do an n.tail() command, I see the missing data that ... seems to suggest.

```
print n.tail()
    Species    ppm as ion  Cycles  Temp F   pH
68      OH-  5.516061e-03       5      86  7.3
69    CaOH+  6.097815e-04       5      86  7.3
70    HSO4-  5.395493e-06       5      86  7.3
71  CaHSO4+  2.632098e-07       5      86  7.3
73       O2  1.783007e-35       5      86  7.3

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

If I count the number of rows showing up on the screen, I get 60. If I add the 5 extra that show up with n.tail(), I get the expected 65 rows.  Is there some limit in print that would only allow 60 rows ? What's causing ... at the end of my DataFrame ?

Initially I though there was something in the ion_tab function that was limiting the printing. But one I saw the missing data in the n.tail() statement, I got confused.

Any help in debugging this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas limits the number of rows printed by default.  You can change that with `pd.set_option`

```
In [4]: pd.get_option('display.max_rows')
Out[4]: 60

In [5]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
```